# Try to solve without Jordan theory. $f \in End(\mathbb{R^3})$ prove that $\exists W, \; dim(W)=2$ invariant subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, jordan-normal-form

Using the Jordan normal form for real spaces it should be easy, because the first two vectors of every basis that gives a Jordan matrix generate a 2-dimensional invariant subspace.

Any idea about how to solve it without Jordan?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If the matrix has at least two distinct eigenvalues, then it's easy. The only other two possibilities are that the characteristic polynomial is $(x-\lambda)^3$, or $(x-\lambda)q(x)$ where $q(x)$ is irreducible  quadratic (in which case there isn't even any Jordan form, so the Jordan form approach wouldn't work). In the latter case, look for the nullspace of $q(f)$. In the former, if the eigenspace is one dimensional, look for the nullspace of $(f-\lambda)^2$.

Comment: Please accept my answer in the post below!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think it's possible to use Jordan even in that case. I'm referring to the real Jordan normal form, where a complex eigenvalue generates a 2x2 block in the Jordan matrix.

Comment: That's not a "Jordan form". Jordan forms exist if and only if the charazcteristic polynomial splits. "Complex eigenvalues" don't exist when you are working over $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial $\pi$ of $f$ is of $\deg$ 3, so it admits a real root. We can write $\pi = (x -\lambda)^{n}Q$, with $\gcd(x-\lambda, Q) = 1$ and $\deg(Q) = 0, 1,\text{ or } 2$.

- if $n = 3$. Then $\dim(\ker(f - \lambda Id)^3) = 3$, and $\dim(\ker(f - \lambda Id)) \ge 1$. Take
  $W = \ker(f - \lambda Id)$ or $W =\ker(f - \lambda Id)^2$
- if $n < 3$ so $\deg(Q) \ge 1$, we have $\dim(\ker(f -\lambda Id)^n)\ge 1$, $\dim(\ker(Q(f)) \ge 1$ and $\dim(\ker(f -\lambda Id)^n) + \dim(\ker(Q(f)) = 3$. So $\dim(\ker(Q(f)) = 2$ or $\dim(\ker(f -\lambda Id)^n) = 2$. take $W$ to be
  $\ker(Q(f))$ or $\ker(f -\lambda Id)^n$ accordingly.

Comment: Why can you say that $gcd(x-\lambda,Q)=1$?

Comment: @stew.ita I have edited the post, we work with characteristic polynomial now!